# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconFactory::__construct()

Tags: typo3

After following the composer installation guide for [v10 of typo3](https://get.typo3.org/version/10). I pointed apache vhost to the public folder. Once I navigate to the index.php location in the browser, I get this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconFactory::__construct()
0 passed in /home/user/projects/typo3/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php
on line 3423
and exactly 2 expected in
/home/user/projects/typo3/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Imaging/IconFactory.php:71
```

It looks like a dependency injection problem. Please can anybody help with this error

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today and it occured because I was XClass'ing one of the Core Classes and used `GeneralUtility::makeInstance(IconFactory::class)` in this code.
The fix is to use DI in this class, just as you suggested. Also flush all caches afterwards to rebuild the DI container.

From this:

```php
class CTypeList extends AbstractList
{
    public function itemsProcFunc(&$params)
    {
            $fieldHelper = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(MASK\Mask\Helper\FieldHelper::class);
            $storageRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(MASK\Mask\Domain\Repository\StorageRepository::class);
            ...
```

To this:

```php
class CTypeList extends AbstractList
{

    protected StorageRepository $storageRepository;
    protected FieldHelper $fieldHelper;

    public function __construct(StorageRepository $storageRepository, FieldHelper $fieldHelper)
    {
        $this->storageRepository = $storageRepository;
        $this->fieldHelper = $fieldHelper;
    }

    public function itemsProcFunc(&$params)
    {
        $this->storageRepository->doStuff();
        $this->fieldHelper->doStuff();
        ...
```

#### For future reference for others:

This can also happen in own extensions when the Core uses `GeneralUtility::makeInstance` on your classes. (e.g. in AuthenticationServices).
The trick here is to make these DI services public like so:

```yaml
(in extension_path/Configuration/Serivces.yaml)

services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

  Vendor\ExtensionName\Service\FrontendOAuthService:
    public: true
```

Here's documentation for it:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/DependencyInjection/Index.html#knowing-what-to-make-public

Answer (score 1):

For me this issue occured after moving an existing project from a server into DDEV (which is similar to changing the path/URL by a vhost config). My guess is it has to do with changed paths/URLs in cached files. This is how I solved it:

A) Manually delete all cached files:

```
t3project$ rm -rf public/typo3temp/*
t3project$ rm -rf var/*
```

B) Also I had to change the ownership of some autogenerated folders/files to my current user (`sudo chown -R myuser:myuser t3project/`), then I was able to use the "Fix folder structure" tool in "Environment > Directory Status", now everything was working fine again. Not sure if the last step is helpful for you, as it might be only related to my case where certain folder/files had a wrong owner as they was copied.

Comment: Tried these and it did not work. Error message is exactly the same as OP, using nginx 1.14.2 and PHP 7.3. The issue is that you cannot even enter any sort of web interface of Typo3, i.e. your "Fix folder structure" recommendation cannot be used. Typo3 Troubleshooting does not help, either.

Comment: Yes I know, the error is thrown for frontend and backend. But in my case I could open the install-tool after deleting all generated temp files (`cache`, `lock`, `log`, `session` etc). Like I said, step B) might be optional, but I wasn't sure. I have tested this solution twice on two different projects, and both times the error was gone after step A).

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because i used the `Services.yaml` file in one of my extensions, but did not configure it correct.

More infos about the file itself can be found [here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/DependencyInjection/Index.html#configure-dependency-injection-in-extensions)

Since the file is responsible for the dependency injection, small mistakes e.g. in namespaces lead to the above mentioned error.

To locate the error you can uninstall extensions with a `Services.yaml`.
When you have found the file/extension, you have to check if all Namespaces in the `Classes` Directory are correct.
This means:

- All filenames are correct regarding the Class they contains
- All Namespaces in the files are correct for path and filename
- The Namespace can be found via composer. So the extension have to be installed via composer or must have an entry in the *autoload* list of `composer.json`